# Getting error on Elastic Search query [ImageURL] query malformed, no start_object after query name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following request JSON for ES query. It gives me following error:

> [ImageURL] query malformed, no start_object after query name

when i add `must_not` under `bool`. if i remove `must_not`, it works fine. I want to get records where "ImageURL" is not null

Where i am doing wrong? Please help

```
{
        "from": 0,
        "size": 45,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": [
                    [{
                        "term": {
                            "PostStatusInd": 1
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "PostCountry": "PAK"
                        }
                    }], {
                        "range": {
                            "RecModDate": {
                                "gte": "2019-07-07 00:00:00"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "range": {
                            "PostPriceAmt": {
                                "gte": "0",
                                "lte": "100000000"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "41000km",
                            "Location": {
                                "lat": "33.6895939",
                                "lon": "73.0435789"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "must_not": {
                    "ImageURL": null
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [{
            "RecModDate": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"exists" worked for me

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 45,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "ImageURL"
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                [{
                    "term": {
                        "PostStatusInd": 1
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "PostCountry": "PAK"
                    }
                }], {
                    "range": {
                        "RecModDate": {
                            "gte": "2019-07-07 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "range": {
                        "PostPriceAmt": {
                            "gte": "0",
                            "lte": "100000000"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "41000km",
                        "Location": {
                            "lat": "33.6895939",
                            "lon": "73.0435789"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "RecModDate": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you missed writing the term/match function within must_not query

Try the below query

{
        "from": 0,
        "size": 45,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": [
                    [{
                        "term": {
                            "PostStatusInd": 1
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "PostCountry": "PAK"
                        }
                    }], {
                        "range": {
                            "RecModDate": {
                                "gte": "2019-07-07 00:00:00"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "range": {
                            "PostPriceAmt": {
                                "gte": "0",
                                "lte": "100000000"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "41000km",
                            "Location": {
                                "lat": "33.6895939",
                                "lon": "73.0435789"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "must_not": {
                  "term":{
                    "ImageURL": null
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [{
            "RecModDate": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }]
    }
```